# What is recordoffset in read method of eventlog in sigar ? I used the recordnumber as parameter in read method and it throwing an exception

Tags: java, sigar

RecorNumber - 7518

A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:

EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x000000005ae52fa5, pid=3516, tid=4280

JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (7.0_51-b13) (build 1.7.0_51-b13)
 Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (24.51-b03 mixed mode windows-amd64 compressed oops)
 Problematic frame:
 V  [jvm.dll+0x122fa5]

Failed to write core dump. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of Windows

An error report file with more information is saved as:
C:\workspace\Test\hs_err_pid3516.log

If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
  http://bugreport.sun.com/bugreport/crash.jsp